# Eclipse plug-in: nameFilter of propertyPages takes a strange effect

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I use Eclipse SDK Mars.1(4.5.1). I create a propertyPages plug-in.
In plugin.xml:
If I change value of “nameFilter” to “*.txt”, then only when I select .txt file, the propertyPage item can appear in left of the properties dialog;
If I change value of “nameFilter” to “*.java” or “*.xml” or even “*.*”, then still only when I select .txt file, the propertyPage item can appear.
Here is my plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
      <page
            id="com.def.btp_property_3.properties.BTPPropertyPage"
            name="BTP Page"
            class="com.def.btp_property_3.properties.BTPPropertyPage"
            nameFilter="*.java">
         <enabledWhen>
            <instanceof
                  value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
            </instanceof>
         </enabledWhen>
       </page>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Can anyone tell me the reason and give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the enableWhen use:

```xml
<enabledWhen>
   <or>
      <instanceof
            value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
      </instanceof>
      <adapt
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
      </adapt>
   </or>
</enabledWhen>
```

User interface elements in views are often not instances of `IFile`, instead they are some other object which can be 'adapted' to `IFile`. This enabledWhen deals with this case.